# pass /dev/disk to lxc container

Tags: lxc

Before we used `fstab`:

```
/dev/disk      /var/lib/lxc/<container>/rootfs/dev/disk        none  bind,create=dir     0       0
```

But after upgrade to lxc 1.1.5 this solution doesn't work.

Also if we make parted to create some partitions in host system, forlders "disk" and "block" magicaly appear in lxc container /dev

Comment: You need to put in more details.  What do you mean "doesn't work", for example.  What are you actually trying to achieve? What actually happens.

Comment: I mean that in container not appear /dev/disk forlder. We use it to get access to /dev/disk/by-partuuid. Because program that we isolate in lxc use links from this folder, to identify disk

Comment: So sorry we just forget to pass lxc.mount in config. Now alll workr perfectly